# Decimal Display

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I'd like to display decimals in the following way:

```
3 = 3.00
3.1 = 3.10 
3.111 = 3.111
3.111000 = 3.111
```

Basically a min of 2 decimals, but more decimals displayed if necessary.  The exception is if there are only 0 remaining, then it shouldn't display the 0s at the end past 2 decimals.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a custom format of `0.00##########`, it's going to show the first two decimals, and then after that only if there's a non-zero digit.

[image]